# How to solve about Docker error about failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt?

Tags: docker

I use this `docker build - < Dockerfile  -t deepface` to build a docker image.

When I runin command it show Error:

```
> ERROR [3/4] COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt                 
> 0.0s
> ------
>  > [3/4] COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt:
> ------ failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

My Director File is

```
 >Deepface
 |->Dockerfile
 |->requirements.txt
```

My requirements.txt is

```
numpy==1.19.5
pandas==1.2.4
gdown==3.13.0
tqdm==4.60.0
Pillow==8.2.0
opencv-python==4.5.2.52
tensorflow==2.5.0
keras==2.4.3
Flask==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.4.2
deepface==0.0.53
```

and my Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /code 
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt 
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This could be related to [this BuildKit docker issue](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1939).

In order to see if this is indeed the problem, try building with BuildKit disabled:

```
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build ...
```

If this helps, then you can try one of these for a permanent fix:

1. Update docker (or follow the above linked GitHub issue to see if it is fixed)
2. Disable BuildKit globally by adding
   `{ "features": { "buildkit": true } }`
   to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
   (or `c:\Users\CURRENT_USER\.docker\daemon.json` on Windows).

As a side note, I would recommend avoiding copying `requirements.txt` to the root folder of the container. Use a subdirectory, such as `/app` and use `WORKDIR` in your `Dockerfile` to make it the base directory.

As a secondary side note - instead of running
`docker build - < Dockerfile ...` you can just run
`docker build ...`

Answer (score 1):

The particular `docker build` syntax you use

```sh
docker build - <Dockerfile
```

has *only* the Dockerfile; nothing else is in the Docker [build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description), and so you can't `COPY` anything into the image.  Even though this syntax is [in the `docker build` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files) I wouldn't use it.

A more typical invocation is to just specify the current directory as the build context:

```sh
docker build -t deepface .
```

(Don't forget to also `COPY` your application code into the image, and set the standard `CMD` the container should run.)

Answer (score 1):

## 1. WHY?

Whenever you *piped through STDIN `Dockerfile`* you can't use `ADD` and `COPY` instructions within local paths.

There is a trick. Docker can use paths only in scope of so called *context*.

*Context* is a directory you specify for `docker build`. E.g. `docker build my-docker-context-dir`. But as long as you use `STDIN` instead of directory *there is no directory*.

In this case *docker is absolutely blind to everything but the contents of `Dockerfile`*. Read this official [*Build with -*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--)

Perhaps its also worth reading whole [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) section. Frankly at first I also skipped it, and got some pitfalls just like you.

## 2. What to do?

Whenever you want to put some files into docker image, *you have to create a context directory*.

So your directory structure should be like this:

```
 >Deepface
 |->Dockerfile
 |->context-dir
    |->requirements.txt
```

Now you can call `docker build` as follows (note, there is a `-t` option as proposed by David Maze):

```sh
cd Deepface
docker build -t deepface -f Dockerfile context-dir
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the file may be in the `.dockerignore` file, please check if the file is not there.